# How to remove commas from between multiple authors (Biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am using numeric-comp style. As can be seen from the quoted text, between authors commas and full-stops are together, ie   Smith, J., Berry, M.,

I dont know if this is normal style in Biblatex but it looks messy to me. Can I remove the commas between mutiple authors? My log window says I am using style biblatex.bst

Here is my MWE,

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
natbib=true,
dashed=false,
sorting=none,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=10,
firstinits=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
eprint=false,
defernumbers=true,
abbreviate=false,
style=numeric-comp]{biblatex} 

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\setlength\bibitemsep{3.5\itemsep}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]
{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]
{volume}{ {#1} } 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inproceedings, incollection, inbook]
{pages}{p. #1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
    \printfield{volume}
    \printfield{number}
    \printunit{\addcolon}
}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and here is an example of how the types of reference are outputted

> - [5] Krueger, J., Koch, V., and Hoelsch, R. Future Legislation on Noise and Emission of Vehicles and the Impact on the Design of Exhaust Systems. 9th International Styrian Noise, Vibration & Harshness Congress: The European Automotive Noise Conference. SAE International, 2016.
> - [6] Moore, D. Development of ECE R51.03 Noise Emission Regulation. Noise and Vibration Conference and Exhibition. SAE International, 2017.
> - [7] Wolfindale, A., Dunne, G., and Walsh, S. Vehicle noise primary attribute balance. Applied Acoustics 73 (4):2012, p. 386 –394.

This is for [5] Krueger

```
@inproceedings{4,
    author={Krueger, Jan and Koch, Viktor and Hoelsch, Ralf},
    title={Future Legislation on Noise and Emission of Vehicles and the Impact on the Design of Exhaust Systems},
    booktitle={9th International Styrian Noise, Vibration \& Harshness Congress: The European Automotive Noise Conference},
    publisher={SAE International},
    month={jun},
    year={2016},
    doi={https://doi.org/10.4271/2016-01-1843},
    url={https://doi.org/10.4271/2016-01-1843},
    issn={0148-7191},
```

I would like to have the references like this (but is the considered normal?)

> - [5] Krueger, J. Koch, V. and Hoelsch, R. Future Legislation on Noise and Emission of Vehicles and the Impact on the Design of Exhaust Systems. 9th International Styrian Noise, Vibration & Harshness Congress: The European Automotive Noise Conference. SAE International, 2016.
> - [6] Moore, D. Development of ECE R51.03 Noise Emission Regulation. Noise and Vibration Conference and Exhibition. SAE International, 2017.
> - [7] Wolfindale, A. Dunne, G. and Walsh, S. Vehicle noise primary attribute balance. Applied Acoustics 73 (4):2012, p. 386 –394.

Comment: So you want *Smith, J. Berry, M.*? BTW: Please consider showing us an example that we can actually compile instead of just a code snippet. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864

Comment: Okay Ive edit my post

@moewe yes Smith, J. Berry, M. is how I would like it. But is this considered normal standard or is Smith, J., Berry, M., normal?

Comment: Your code is more minimal now, which is very good. But unfortunately it is still not compilable. Compilable LaTeX code will almost always have a `\documentclass` and a `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Ideally you would check that your example is compilable for others by copying it into a new, empty directory on your PC and compiling it. If the example compiles, everything is fine. If things are missing, the example is not minimal.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how to set up a document, im using my university's template

Comment: Then build a simple document with `\documentclass{article}` around the code you have here. Include a few example entries with `filecontents` as shown in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. In fact you can take the code in that link as basis and combine it with yours to obtain a proper MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say that I find the desired output

> [image: Krueger, J. Koch, V. and Hoelsch, R.]

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace}
```

slightly confusing. At first glance I might think the second author is "J. Koch", this effect is more pronounced with larger numbers of authors.

I have seen

> [image: Krueger J., Koch V. and Hoelsch R.]

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
```

before, which works a bit better for me although it is certainly unusual for my eyes not to see a comma when the names are inverted. This is sometimes combined with leaving out the dot of the initial as well

> [image: Krueger J, Koch V and Hoelsch R]

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{terseinits=true}
```

You could also cut down the number of commas by choosing the `given-family` name order

> [image: J. Krueger, V. Koch and R. Hoelsch]

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family}
```

The visual impression of 'too much punctuation' in too little space could also be mitigated by printing full given names and not just initials

> [image: Krueger, Jan, Koch, Viktor and Hoelsch, Ralf]

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{giveninits=false}
```

in which case I think the French tradition of small caps for family names can make it easier to parse the names quickly.

> [image: Krueger, Jan, Koch, Viktor and Hoelsch, Ralf]

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{giveninits=false}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
```

Comment: Your 3rd code block is great. This will be the one I will use